# populating UIPickerView with 4 components?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIPickerView where the numberOfComponentsInPickerView=4.
But how do I populate each component, as they have different value ranges?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by implementing `– pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:` of the pickers datasource.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 4;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    if (component == 0){
         return 5;
    } else if (component == 1){
         return 3;
    } else if (component == 2){
         return 10;
    } else if (component == 3){
         return 5;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

and the pickerView's delegate
either `– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` or `– pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`

If the components change, you can call `[aPickerView reloadComponent:<numberOfComponent>]`
or `[aPickerView reloadAllComponents]` if even the number of components changes.

The [dataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDataSource) and the [viewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDelegate) documentation.

**edit**
I just put my very first iPhone program on GitHub, that is a coffee configuration based on a 3 or 4 component picker: You can select amount, kind and one option for every coffee. Except for Latte — there you can choose two different options. You will find it in this [repository as "M18Coffee"](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples). **As I said: my very first program — might be rough**.

Comment: I put my first program I wrote online. It uses a picker. BTW: Do not hesitate and vote up!